# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{(\sqrt4+\sqrt x)−(\sqrt4-\sqrt x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I’m absolutely lost on how to do this question.

> How to evaluate 
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{(\sqrt4+\sqrt x)−(\sqrt4-\sqrt x)}?$$

I know that I have to multiply the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate, which should be $${(\sqrt4+\sqrt x) + (\sqrt4-\sqrt x)}$$
But the square roots are throwing me off. I’ve tried separating them individually but then I get a $\sqrt{-x}$ for ${(\sqrt4-\sqrt x)}$ which isn’t possible. I tried putting the minus sign outside of the square root sign but I’m not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: Since the function is only defined for $\;\sqrt4\neq x>0\;$ , you actually want the limit $\;x\to0^+\;$ (from the right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice that $\;(\sqrt4+\sqrt x)-(\sqrt4-\sqrt x)=2\sqrt x\;$, things are pretty simpler...So simple that it looks almost trivial. Check you copied the question correctly

Comment: Opssss...I didn't notice that!!! :)

Comment: It does seem much simpler, thank you! It was actually the first thing I did, however when I reread the question I was given, I was told to specifically use conjugation. But I think I understand what I did wrong and what to do now - I presumed I needed to use conjugation before simplifying the function and thus, it made my life a little bit harder. This was such a huge help and it’s very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$\frac{x}{(\sqrt4+\sqrt x)−(\sqrt4-\sqrt x)}=\frac{x}{2\sqrt x}=\frac{x}{2\sqrt x}\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}=\ldots$$